# Using ip addresses in place of domain names for cookies

Tags: http, cookies

Our servers that processes REST client requests currently is not mapped to a public domain name. Is it mandatory to have a domain name when generating Client side cookies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a requirement.  The cookie will get associated with the IP address as if that was the host name.